# Program is done in Java (Netbeans), how do I get it out to people so they can easily run it via Windows, Linux and Mac?

Tags: netbeans, jar, build, final

So I built my program blah blah blah.

In the dist folder, I have my .jar, obviously, and the other dependencies the lib folder.

So I do javaw -jar name.jar and it runs perfectly fine, however, it has the cmd.exe box still there.  I do the @echo off and it won't print anything, but it still shows the black box.

So basically, how can I run this without anything coming up?

Further, I can easily make a shortcut, have the user put it on their desktop or w/e.  But how can I have it so that the user double clicks and it runs (Like an .exe)?

Further more, how does this work on Mac/Linux?  I don't use Mac, and rarely use Linux, so I don't know how this all works.

If you have any links or google searches, that works.  I couldn't find anything for about an hour/10+ searches, so I'm giving up hah.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q: So basically, how can I run this without anything coming up?

A: Use "javaw -jar " instead of "java".

On Windows, you have several choices:

1. Write a .bat file that calls "start javaw -jar myprog.jar"
2. Instruct the user how to set their filetype associations in Windows Explorer (so that double-clicking a .jar automatically invokes "javaw")
3. Etc

Here's a good link that covers both Windows and Linux:

http://www.wikihow.com/Run-a-.Jar-Java-File

Comment: I said in the post that I did javaw -jar and that it still showed the cmd window.  Basically, I used start in front of the javaw -jar and it got rid of it.  But thanks regardless.